# Copy entire row from one table to another in MYSQL trigger

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with identical schemas, I want to copy the newly inserted record from table1 to table2 in a trigger, my code is below and works, but only copies the id field

```
BEGIN
   insert into Table2 (id) values (new.id);
END
```

However the table many columns, is there a way to copy the entire record into the table2 without specifying all the columns and values, like below

```
BEGIN
   insert into Table2 SELECT * FROM NEW;
END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
  insert into Table2 SELECT * FROM Table1 where id=new.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second SQL is fine but you have to do one query first for using the star in your select into :

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT NEW ON
```

And then :

```
BEGIN
   insert into Table2 SELECT * FROM NEW;
END
```

And dont forget to put it OFF at the end

**EDIT 1**

If it's not working, maybe try to put some priority on your sql :

```
INSERT INTO `Table2` (SELECT * FROM `NEW`);
```

**EDIT 2**

If it's still not working, maybe you could try to create the table with all the element directly :

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 [AS] SELECT * FROM NEW;
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, but mysql does not seem to support IDENTIY_INSERT,  its giving me an error

Comment: I have made some edit on my post, could you try this ? and also, could you give us the version of your mysql, it could help

Comment: mysql 5.6.34-79.1,  sorry but neither of those edits worked for me